# List Open TCP connections in Java

Tags: java, linux, tcp, tcpclient

I was wondering how I could list all the TCP connections on my system which are open using Java. I am using CentOS.

I do not have any clue on where to start also. Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Thanks for the tips
I have to do something like this

Q)  Identify any new established connections for all tcp ports that are currently listening
    and continue to poll every 5 seconds. The script should terminate when there are no longer any established connections.

```
public class TCPConnections {

    public HashSet<Integer> establishedConnections = new HashSet<Integer>();
    public HashSet<Integer> listeningConnections = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TCPConnections tcpConnections = new TCPConnections();
        try{        
            do{    
                tcpConnections.getListeningConnections();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                tcpConnections.getEstablishedConnections();    
            }while(!tcpConnections.establishedConnections.isEmpty());    
        }    
        catch(Exception ex){    
            ex.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }

    public void getEstablishedConnections(){
        String netstat = new String();    
        try {    
                String line;
                establishedConnections = new HashSet<Integer>();
                String[] cmd = {    
                        "/bin/sh",    
                        "-c",    
                        "netstat -atn | grep -w tcp | grep ESTABLISHED"    
                        };

                java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {    
                    String[] portNo = line.split("\\s+");    
                    if(portNo[3] != null && !portNo[3].equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){    
                        String str = portNo[3].split(":")[1];    
                        if( str != null && str.matches("[0-9]+")){    
                            establishedConnections.add(Integer.parseInt(str));    
                            if(listeningConnections.contains(Integer.parseInt(str))){listeningConnections.remove(Integer.parseInt(str));  
                                System.out.println(" New connection established on port : "+Integer.parseInt(str));    
                            }    
                        }    
                    }    
                        netstat = netstat + " \n" + line;    
                }    
                System.out.println(netstat);    
                input.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {    
                err.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }

    public void getListeningConnections(){    
        String netstat = new String();    
        try {    
                String line;    
                listeningConnections = new HashSet<Integer>();
                String[] cmd = {    
                        "/bin/sh",    
                        "-c",    
                        "netstat -atn | grep -w tcp | grep LISTEN"    
                        };
                java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);    
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));    
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {    
                    String[] portNo = line.split("\\s+");    
                    if(portNo[3] != null && !portNo[3].equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){    
                        String str = portNo[3].split(":")[1];    
                        if( str != null && str.matches("[0-9]+")){    
                            listeningConnections.add(Integer.parseInt(str));                        
                        }   
                    }       
                        netstat = netstat + " \n" + line;    
                }    
                System.out.println(netstat);    
                input.close();          
        } catch (Exception err) {    
                err.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }    
}
```

The problem I face is that few ports are always in the established state and few are always in the Listen state so that the do-while loop runs forever. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This would be most efficient using operating system level tools. So Java is not the best language to use here. You are probably best off using some kind of console command from Java if Java is really required.

Comment: can I use netstat in java exec???

Comment: Why? netstat already exists.

Comment: Hmm, are you in the same class as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093360)?

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be anything built-in to Java to support this, which isn't surprising because `netstat`-like functionality is OS-dependent.

You have two other options:

1) Parse the output of `netstat`:

```
$ netstat -tn
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.140:48352     74.125.225.134:80       ESTABLISHED
```

2) Parse [`/proc/net/tcp`](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0409.1/2166.html) (and `tcp6`, `udp`, `udp6`, `unix`, if you care):

```
$ cat /proc/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
   0: 0100007F:0277 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 17120 1 ffff8800797c4700 100 0 0 10 0
   1: 0100007F:0019 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 14821 1 ffff8800797c4000 100 0 0 10 0
   2: 8C01A8C0:BCE0 86E17D4A:0050 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 20164 1 ffff8800797c4e00 24 0 0 10 -1
```

This may appear more daunting, but would be the preferred method, as it doesn't rely upon `netstat` being present (and in your `PATH`, etc.)

Comment: parsing `/proc/net/tcp`:  https://gist.github.com/jkstill/5095725

Answer (score 1):

You could use SNMP to get the `TCPConnTable` or `TCPConnectionTable`, whichever is supported.

There is a Java SNMP library called NetSNMP, no doubt others as well.